# Найти числа между максимальным и минимальным в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.x, срез

Имеется массив A из N произвольных чисел. Найти максимальное и минимальное число. Напечатать те элементы массива, которые находятся между ними. Я только учусь и поэтому смог только написать это:

```py
A = []
N = int(input('Сколько в массиве будет элементов '))

for i in range(N):
    A.append(int(input()))

a1 = max(A)
a2 = min(A)
```

Comment: Есть смысл количество N элементов наполнить рандомными значениями rand.int  Потом можно отсортировать и взять первое либо последнее. Но min/max тоже хорошо

Comment: @BlayWille min/max тут не вариант, сортировать тоже незачем...

Comment: @Jack_oS Да, я прочитал только первое предложение, согласен, не вариант. Под рукой ноута нет, думаю просто перебор с ord, , ключ массива, то да се..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = []
n = int(input('Сколько в массиве будет элементов '))

for i in range(n):
    array.append(int(input(f'{i+1}-е число: ')))
```

допустим, после заполнения вы получили такой список:

```
[3, 5, -1, 2, 13, 42, 3, 7, 1]
```

вам нужны индексы минимального и максимального элемента:

```
index_min = index_max = 0
value_min = value_max = array[0]

for i, a in enumerate(array[1:], 1):
    if a < value_min:
        value_min = a
        index_min = i
    if a > value_max:
        value_max = a
        index_max = i
```

зная их, выведите срезом то, что между ними:

```
>>> print(array[index_min+1:index_max])
[2, 13]
```

UPD Если индекс минимального элемента может быть больше индекса максимального, перед срезом стОит это проверить:

```
if index_min < index_max:
    print(array[index_min+1:index_max])
else:
    print(array[index_max+1:index_min])
```

Спасибо [CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/260769/crazyelf) за уточнение!

Comment: Тщательнее надо ) Функции min и max перекрывать нехорошо. Индекс минимума не обязательно будет меньше индекса максимума. В этом случае срез сработает?

Comment: "Индекс минимума не обязательно будет меньше индекса максимума" как раз это и обдумываю... нет, конечно...

Comment: Как на счет такого варианта `res = array[min(index_min, index_max)+1 : max(index_min, index_max)]` ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
A = []
N = int(input('Сколько в массиве будет элементов '))

for i in range(N):
    A.append(int(input()))

index_min, index_max = A.index(min(A)), A.index(max(A))
l, r = sorted([index_min, index_max])

print(A[l:r+1])
```

`index_min, index_max = A.index(min(A)), A.index(max(A))` ищет индексы минимума и максимума.

`l, r = sorted([index_min, index_max])` упорядочивает индексы минимума и максимума для того, чтобы соотнести их с левой и правой границами среза.